# How to save changes back to databse from jsTree?

Tags: php, json, codeigniter, jstree

I want to save the changes i make on the jsTree back to database. I tried different methods but cant get to work. I am working in codeigniter. Please help me if you can. Thank you.
Here is my code,
view.php:

```
 <button id="target" type="submit">Click here</button>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#tree-container').on('changed.jstree', function (e, data) {
            var i, j, r = [];
            // var state = false; 
            for (i = 0, j = data.selected.length; i < j; i++) {
                r.push(data.instance.get_node(data.selected[i]).id);
            }
            $('#txttuser').val(r.join(','));
        }).jstree({
            'plugins': ["checkbox", "dnd", "search", "contextmenu"],
            'core': {
                "check_callback" : true,
                "multiple": true,
                'data': {
                    "url": "getChildren",
                    "dataType": "json"
                }
            },
            'checkbox': {
                three_state: false,
                cascade: 'up'
            },
            'plugins': ["dnd","contextmenu","search","wholerow"],
        }
        );
    });

   $( "#target" ).click(function() { 
       var v =$('#tree-container').jstree(true).get_json();      
       var mytext = JSON.stringify(v);      
       alert(mytext); });
</script>

<div class="row"> 
    <div class="container"> 
        <input type="hidden" name="node" id="node" value="" /> 
        <div class="form-group"> <div id="tree-container"></div> 
        </div> 
    </div> 
</div>
```

controller.php:

```
 function getChildren() { 

    $this->load->model('Category_model');

    $result = $this->Category_model->tree_all(); 

    $itemsByReference = array(); 
 // Build array of item references: 
        foreach($result as $key => &$item) { 
        $itemsByReference[$item['category_id']] = &$item; 
 // Children array:
        $itemsByReference[$item['category_id']]['children'] = array(); 
 // Empty data class (so that json_encode adds "data: {}" ) 
        $itemsByReference[$item['category_id']]['data'] = new StdClass(); 

    } 
 // Set items as children of the relevant parent item. 
    foreach($result as $key => &$item) 
        if($item['parent_id'] &&       isset($itemsByReference[$item['parent_id']])) 
            $itemsByReference [$item['parent_id']]['children'][] = &$item; 


 // Remove items that were added to parents elsewhere: 
    foreach($result as $key => &$item) { 
        if($item['parent_id'] &&    isset($itemsByReference[$item['parent_id']])) 
            unset($result[$key]); 



    } 

    foreach ($result as $row) { 
        $data[] = $row; 

    } 
 // Encode: 
echo json_encode($data); 

    }
```

model.php:

```
 function tree_all() { 
$result = $this->db->query("SELECT category_id, category,category as text,   parent_id FROM category ")->result_array(); 
foreach ($result as $row) { 
    $data[] = $row; 

} 
    return $data; 

}
```

Pleeaaase heeelp meee!!! I am trying to figure this out for days.

Comment: **I want to save the changes i make on the jsTree back to database** by this line you mean the select / deselected you have done on jstree checkbox ?

Comment: No. Create, remove, rename, edit and drag n drop.

Comment: Not getting you!

Comment: In the jsTree you can create rename modify delete nodes. when im deleteng a node it doesnt delete from the database(server) and when i refresh the page the "deleted" node is still there for example.

Comment: Ok, you have to handle all these events and use `ajax()` to update the data in database for each action

Comment: Yes. Thats the problem. Im pretty new at programming and i dont know how to that. I worked with jTable mostly.

Comment: @BenedekTas  Hi were you able to implement this? If yes, can you post your implementation as an answer please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To manage add, edit, update with JSTree, first of all download the `jstree.js` and check the following line:

```
"create" : {
```

this is the block of code which is executes when you click on create, put your create code logic here with an ajax call to `add / update` database.

In the same way you can manage `edit`, `delete`.

**Note:** `edit`, `delete` is just after the `create`

Ajax syntax:

```
$.ajax({
  url : '<?php echo base_url().'/controllerfunction' ?>',
  method : 'post',
  data: {
    key : value
  },
  success: function(response)  // response from controller function
  {
     // your code here
  }
});
```

Comment: yep. i understnad that but i dont know how to write the ajax call. :( i found the function's.